# How to process the data which type is BLOB?

Tags: database

I get the following data from MySQL by `db_query()`. The type of the column is BLOB.

> a:2:{s:10:"attributes";a:1:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";}s:8:"langcode";s:7:"zh-hans";}

How should I process it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it to [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). That is the string obtained from [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), when the argument is the following array.

```
$array = array(
  'attributes' => array('title' => ''),
  'langcode' => 'zh-hans',
);
```

`serialize()` is the function used from Drupal when the data to save in the database is an array.